# Menu option in menubar isn't showing

Tags: java, swing, menu, awt, jung

This is also happening to the demo that comes with the library. Its like the menu is hidden behind the canvas.

http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p199/paliey87/jung.jpg

I only manage to make it appear if I resize the window and hide the 'white' canvas area.

http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p199/paliey87/jung2.jpg

Any clue what is it behaving like this?

Comment: Thanks man. Manage to solve the problem by setting the popup menu;

 JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess it is due to [mixing light & heavyweight components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/).   The description was sufficient that I did not need to see the screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with z-ordering.

Right click the part that hides your menu, select Order > Send to back

Not sure about the exact menu command, but you should find something similar.